# Dropdown option - redirect or display text

Tags: javascript, html

Depending on the option selected, I would like to display text or redirect to another page.

I used the code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function dropdownTip(value){
    console.log(value);
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = value;
    }</script>
```

```html
<select onChange="dropdownTip(this.value)" name="search_type" style="margin-right:10px; margin-top:2px;">
    <option selected="selected" value="fruit_search">fruits</option>    
    <option value="veggies_search">veggies</option>
    <option value="/contact.html">animals</option>
    <option value="all_search">all</option>
</select>

<div id="result"></div>
```

When I select option then text display correct. But When I select option Animals I want redirect to other page.   But instead of redirecting it also displays the text.

Any solution?

update 2:
I try first solution but no work (no display text and no redirect) something went wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function dropdownTip(value){
    console.log(value);
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = value;
if (value === "animals") {
    window.location.replace("http://www.url.com/contact.html");
else if (value === "all_search") {
    window.location.replace("http://www.url.com/all_search.html");
    }</script>

<select onChange="dropdownTip(this.value)" name="search_type" style="margin-right:10px; margin-top:2px;">
    <option selected="selected" value="fruit_search">fruits</option>    
    <option value="veggies_search">veggies</option>
    <option value="animals_search">animals</option>
    <option value="all_search">all</option>
</select>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect to a page, you need to use **window.location.href**.

Modify **dropdownTip** method

```
function dropdownTip(value){
    if(value === '/contact.html'){
      window.location.href = value;
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = value;
}
```

Comment: working correct your solution. But how can I expand it? Ultimately, I will have, for example, 10 options that display text, and 3 options that redirect. How can I add several options to the script that redirect?

Comment: There are several ways to do it. You can keep an array of redirect locations like **var locations =  ['/contact.html', '/about.html', '/home.html']**. Now on the condition, you will check **(locations.includes(value))** instead **(value === '/contact.html')** .

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value, then redirect if it equals to "animals":

```
function dropdownTip(value){
  if (value === "animals") {
    window.location.replace("http://www.url.com/contact.html");
  }
}
```